# Getting Index Value of Drop down list always stored as 0 in connected database.Also i have enabled the autopostback in html source

Tags: c#, asp.net

Have include my C# code.Please help me to accomplish the task

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Project1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TEST"].ToString());
        string str;
        int compId;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // calProjectDate.Visible = false;
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TEST"].ToString());
                con.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = " Select * FROM COMPANY";
                cmd.Connection = con;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                ddlCompanyName.DataSource = dt;
                ddlCompanyName.DataTextField = "COMPANYNAME";
                ddlCompanyName.DataValueField = "COMPANYID";
                ddlCompanyName.DataBind();
                ddlCompanyName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name--"));
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        protected void btnShowCalendar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            calProjectDate.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void calDateofBirth_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtProjectDate.Text = calProjectDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

            calProjectDate.Visible = false;
        }
        protected void calProjectDate_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtProjectDate.Text = calProjectDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

                str = ddlCompanyName.SelectedItem.Text;
                //int value = ddlCompanyName.DataValueField.OfType.s;


               // int selectedradioValue = this.RblGender.TabIndex;
              //  int selectedCompanyValue = this.ddlCompanyName.TabIndex;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CMPPOJECT(PROJECTNAME,DESCRIPTION,COMPANY,WEBSITEURL,COMPLETEDIN,STARTEDIN)VALUES('" + txtProjectName.Text + "','" + txtDescription.Text + "','" + compId + "','" + txtWebsiteUrl.Text + "','" + cbProjectCompleted.Text + "','" + txtProjectDate.Text + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                 Response.Write("<script>alert('Sorry,some error occured! Please try again!')</script>");
        }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                Response.Write("is it coming");
            }
      }
        protected void ddlCompanyName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             compId = ddlCompanyName.SelectedIndex;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: why you have used the function `ddlCompanyName_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: compId = ddlCompanyName.SelectedIndex; this line.... What are you trying to get ? You want to get the Drop Down Index ?

Comment: ya just get rid of selectedIndexchanged event and try to run the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `compId` is always `0` because every time having new PostBack request, the `compId` is initialized and the default value is `0`

You can directly use the value of dropdownlist (**ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue**):

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CMPPOJECT(PROJECTNAME,DESCRIPTION,COMPANY,WEBSITEURL,COMPLETEDIN,STARTEDIN)VALUES('" + txtProjectName.Text + "','" + txtDescription.Text + "','" + ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue + "','" + txtWebsiteUrl.Text + "','" + cbProjectCompleted.Text + "','" + txtProjectDate.Text + "')";
```

Comment: Thanku...Thank u vry much..its working...